# Label lightning input hypertext

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, slds, label

It is possible to render clickable label of a lightning input of the checkbox type?

```
<lightning:layoutItem size="12" class="">
<lightning:inputaura:id="fieldCheckbox"  name="terms"
 type="checkbox"label="{!$Label.c.TermsConditions}"  checked="{!v.terms}"  required="true"/>
</lightning:layoutItem>
```

Desired result:
[image]

Ps: I Use a aura if for the popup

Comment: Can you clarify a bit as what are you trying to achieve? In its current form its not very clear. Please [*edit your question*](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/237803/edit) and provide further details for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry... I hope it's a little clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use `<aura:set attribute="label">` in order to set clickabel link, but no success. SO you can create your custom checkbox, where you can do it.

```
<lightning:input aura:id="fieldCheckbox" name="terms" type="checkbox" label="!$Label.c.TermsConditions}" checked="{!v.terms}"  required="true"/>
```

will be replaces with

```
<div class="slds-form-element__row">
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-checkbox">
            <abbr class="slds-required" title="required">*</abbr>
            <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="terms" name="terms" class="slds-input" value="{!v.terms}" />
            <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"/>
            <span class="slds-form-element__label">
                <a onclick="{!c.showPopup}">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

it looks like: [image] and is clickable

`showPopup` controller method will take care about showing your popup.